# TypeConverterMarkupExtension error on setting ImageSource of UserControl

Tags: c#, wpf, user-controls, dependency-properties

I'm trying to embed an Image into a User Control. I see many posts about this topic, and I tried a lot of combination, but I cannot get it to work.

```
<UserControl x:Class="AudioBoxController.AudioBoxItem"
             x:Name="AudioBoxItemControl"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             mc:Ignorable="d" Width="200" Height="250">
  <Grid>

    <Image Name="image" Margin="10" VerticalAlignment="Center" 
           Source="{Binding Path=ImageSource, Mode=OneWay}"/>

  </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

In code behind I have create a DP for the Image:

```
public partial class AudioBoxItem : UserControl
{
  public AudioBoxItem()
  {
    InitializeComponent();
    DataContext = this;
  }

  public static DependencyProperty SourceProperty =
       DependencyProperty.Register("ImageSource", typeof(ImageSource), typeof(AudioBoxItem));

  public ImageSource ImageSource
  {
    get { return (ImageSource)GetValue(SourceProperty); }
    set { SetValue(SourceProperty, value); }
  }
}
```

Now, in the window I use it:

```
<local:AudioBoxItem x:Name="ctrlMike" 
                    Grid.Column="0"  
                    VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                    ImageSource="/AudioBoxController;component/Images/Speakers.png"/>
```

At design time I correctly see the image, instead, when I run I get the error:

```
A first chance exception of type 'System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException' occurred in PresentationFramework.dll

Additional information: 'An exception was thrown when the specification of a value of
'System.Windows.Baml2006.TypeConverterMarkupExtension'.' line number '19' e line position '60'.
```

Where I'm wrong?

**EDIT**

I changed the source image from "Embedded Resource" to "Content" and I use the relative path:

```
<local:AudioBoxItem x:Name="ctrlMike" 
                    Grid.Column="0"  
                    VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                    ImageSource="Images/Speakers.png"/>
```

In this way it works...so, which syntax I have to use if the image is an "embedded Resource"?

Comment: Have you tried `pack://application:,,,/Images/Speakers.png` ?

Comment: If an image file is to loaded by a [Resource File Pack URI](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970069(v=vs.100).aspx#Resource_File_Pack_URIs___Local_Assembly) (that's what you are doing), its Build Action must be `Resource`, not `Embedded Resource` of `Content`.

Comment: Besides that, you should generally avoid to explicitly set the DataContext of a UserControl (like e.g. `DataContext = this` in your constructor). Better write the binding with a RelativeSource, like `Source="{Binding ImageSource, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}}"`. Setting Mode to OneWay is redundant, because it's one-way by default.

Comment: Thanks @Clemens, now it works. Setting the image as Resource and adding a '/' at the beginning of the URI.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is with your DependencyProperty declaration.

Firstly, `SourceProperty` should be `ImageSourceProperty`

Secondly, I believe you need to add a `PropertyMetadata` argument to your `DependencyProperty` declaration in order to support `OneWay` bindings

```
public static DependencyProperty SourceProperty =
       DependencyProperty.Register("ImageSource", typeof(ImageSource), typeof(AudioBoxItem), new PropertyMetadata(null));
```